# Alternative for initializing properties in the constructor in (Dynamics) CRM

Tags: c#, oop, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm currently working one a custom CRM-style solution (EF/Winforms/OData WebApi) and I wonder how to implement a quite simple requirement:

Let's say there is a simple `Project` entity. It is possible to assign `Tasks` to it. There is a `DefaultTaskResponsible` defined in the `Project.` Whenever a `Task` is created, the `Project`'s `DefaultTaskResponsible` is used as the `Task.Responsible`. But it is possible change the `Task.Responsible` and even set it to null.

So, in a 'normal' programming world, I would use a `Task` constructor accepting the `Project` and set the `Responsible` there:

```
public class Task {
  public Task(Project p) {
    this.Responsible = p.DefaultTaskResponsible;
    ...
  }
}
```

But how should I implement something like this in a CRM-World with Lookup views? In Dynamics CRM (or in my custom solution), there is a `Task` view with a `Project` Lookup field. It does not make sense to use a custom `Task` constructor.

Maybe it is possible to use Business Rules in Dynamics CRM and update the Responsible whenever the Project changes (not sure)?! But how should I deal with the WebApi/OData Client?

If I receive a Post to the `Task` endpoint without a `Responsible` I would like to use the `DefaultTaskResponsible`, e.g.

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/tasks
{  
 "project@odata.bind":"[Organization URI]/api/data/projects(xxx-1)"
}.
```

No `Responsible` was send (maybe because it is an older client), so use the default one. But if a `Responsible` is set, the passed value should be used instead, e.g.

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/tasks
{  
 "project@odata.bind":"[Organization URI]/api/data/projects(xxx-1)",
 "responsible@odata.bind": null
}.
```

In my `TaskController` I only see the `Task` model with the `Responsible` being null, but I don't know if it is null because it was set explicitly or because it wasn't send in the request.
Is there something wrong with my ideas/concepts? I think it is quite common to initialize properties based on other objects/properties, isn't it?

Comment: If you're looking for non-programming ways of doing this, I would recommend a synchronous workflow running on the `Task` entity. The WF can lookup the parent `Project` and determine if it has a `ResponsiblePerson` and copy the value to the `Task` if present. WFs execute on the server and are triggered (unless explicitly disabled) via both the UI and API

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably out of scope for this forum, but it is a subject I am interested in. A few thoughts:

A "Task" is a generic construct which traditionally can be associated with many different types of entities. For example, you might not only have tasks associated with Projects, but also with Customer records and Sales records. To run with your code example it would look like:

```
public Task(Entity parent) {}
```

Then you have to decide whether or not your defaulting of the Responsible party is specific to Projects, or generic across all Entities which have Tasks. If the latter, then our concept looks like this:

```
public Task(ITaskEntity parent) 
{
     this.Responsible = parent.DefaultResponsible; //A property of ITaskEntity
}
```

This logic should be enforced at the database "pre operation" level, i.e. when your CRM application receives a request to create a Task, it should make this calculation, then persist the task to the database. This suggests that you should have a database execution pipeline, where actions can be taken before or after database operations occur. A standard simple execution pipeline looks like this:

Validation -> Pre Operation -> Operation (CRUD) -> Post Operation

Unless you are doing this for fun, I recommend abandoning the project and using an existing CRM system.

Comment: Zach, the project already exists and consists of around 150 quite specialized entities. Because of my problems I consider migrating it to a standard CRM solution and evaluated Dynamics 365/CRM. But I still don't have a clue how to implement my requirements in this environment.
Maybe my design/approach is wrong and I should instead e.g. always set the Responsible based on the DefaultResponsible and also add an OverriddenResponsible property (similar to the overriddencreatedon property in dynamics CRM) or an IsResponsibleOverridden property (similar to IsPriceOverridden on SalesOrderDetail)?